# IEnumerable which returns Prime Numbers: smallest implementation

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Recently I wondered what might be the smallest implementation of an IEumerable which returns a given number of prime numbers. It should fit in this program:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many Primes?");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (line.Trim() == "") break;

        int numPrimes;
        if(!int.TryParse(line.Trim(), out numPrimes)) continue;

        int i = 1;
        foreach(int p in PrimeNumbers(numPrimes))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i++, p);                    
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @vtortola thanks for the very interesting link. This was also about IEnumerables and Iterators, using Primes just as an example algorithm

Comment: What do you mean under "Smallest implementation"? Is it smallest number of characters? Isn't efficiency considered here?

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy lets say number of lines for reasonable formatted,  readable and understandable code excluding comments

Comment: What means _"It should fit in this program"_? You don't accept additional methods?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I wanted some complicated sequence inside `foreach()` i.e. some IEnumerable. The "Prime" is just an example for _complicated sequence_

Comment: wget "http://www.di-mgt.com.au/primes10000.txt" | head -n 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another example of smallest C# program:

```
static IEnumerable<int> PrimeNumbers(int n)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(2, int.MaxValue - 2)
                     .Where(i => ParallelEnumerable.Range(2, Math.Max(0, (int)Math.Sqrt(i) - 1))
                                                   .All(j => i % j != 0))
                     .Take(n);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My attempt looks like this:

```
static IEnumerable<int> PrimeNumbers(int numPrimes)
{
    yield return 2; // first prime number
    for(int n=1, p = 3; n < numPrimes; p+=2)
    {
        if (!checkIfPrime(p)) continue;                                
        n++;
        yield return p;              
    }
}

// p > 2, odd
private static bool checkIfPrime(int p)
{
    for (int t = 3; t <= Math.Sqrt(p); t += 2)
    {
        if (p % t == 0) return false;              
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is an *Iterator* which `yield returns` all the prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> PrimeNumbers(int NumberPrimes)
{
    yield return 2;
    for (int i = 3; i < NumberPrimes; i = i + 2)
    {
        bool IsPrime = true;
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(2, i, (o, state) =>
        {
            if (i % o == 0)
            {
                IsPrime = false;
                state.Break();
            }
        });
        if (IsPrime)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```